# Easily performing the same regression on different datasets

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm performing the same regression on several different datasets (same dependent and independe variables). However, there are many independent variables, and I often want to test adding/removing different variables. I'd like to avoid making all these changes to different lines of code, just because they use different datasets. Can I instead just copy the formula that was used to create some object, and then create a new object using a different dataset? For example, something like:

```
fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ..., data = dataset1)
fit2 <- lm(fit1$call, data = dataset2) # this doesn't work
fit3 <- lm(fit1$call, data = dataset3) # this doesn't work
```

This way, if I want to update numerous regressions, I just update the first one and then rerun them all.

Can this be done? Preferably without using a loop or paste().

Thanks!

Comment: Why no looping structures?

Comment: I'm just looking for a more elegant way. I still may be interested in solutions that utilize loops, but I prefer not using them when possible.

Comment: Interesting.  Loops are generally much more elegant than repeating similar statements over and over IMO.

Comment: While I do think some of the answers below are better, what you have would have worked if you had used `fit$terms` rather than `fit$call`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or use `update`

```
(fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))

# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           wt  
#        37.285       -5.344 

update(fit, data = mtcars[mtcars$hp < 100, ])

# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars[mtcars$hp < 100, ])
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           wt  
#        39.295       -5.379 

update(fit, data = mtcars[1:10, ])

# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars[1:10, ])
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           wt  
#        33.774       -4.285
```

Comment: No need for the leading "Or use" here.

Comment: Awesome answer.  This could be very useful.

Answer (score 5):

Collect your datasets into a `list` and then use `lapply`. E.g.:

```
dsets <- list(dataset1,dataset2,dataset3)
lapply(dsets, function(x) lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=x) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure entirely that this what you want but you can do this as follows:

```
formula <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ...
fit1 <- lm(formula, data = dataset1)
fit2 <- lm(formula, data = dataset2) 
fit3 <- lm(formula, data = dataset3)
```

Comment: Cool. Actually I didn't know you can do this in R. "formula <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ..."