# Use the multiple variables in function in r

Tags: r, function

I have this function

```
ANN<-function (x,y){
DV<-rep(c(0:1),5)
X1<-c(1:10)
X2<-c(2:11)
ANN<-neuralnet(x~y,hidden=10,algorithm='rprop+')
return(ANN)
}
```

I need the function run like

```
    formula=X1+X2
    ANN(DV,formula)
```

and get result of the function. So the problem is to say the function USE the object which was created during the run of function. I need to run trough lapply more combinations of x,y, so I need it this way. Any advices how to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: why? it looks like you are just making a wrapper for `neuralnet` with parameters `hidden = 10, algorithm = 'rprop+'` but complicating things by splitting the `formula` into two parameters. use `ANN(formula)` where `formula` is a valid `?formula` and pass that to `neuralnet`... or did I miss something?

Comment: you could use `update` methinks, does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964993/easily-performing-the-same-regression-on-different-datasets/23965451#23965451) help?

Comment: not a lot. My problem is somewhere else. Let's say I need to say to the function USE the object you have made like (DV,X1,X2) and give me the results. If I would need just neuralnet(DV~X1,...) I need ANN(DV,X1). I hope it is possible, but I cannot find the format to make it run ...

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my answer, this still works for me. Does it work for you? Can you be specific about what sort of errors you are getting?

**New response:**

```
ANN<-function (y){
    X1<-c(1:10)
    DV<-rep(c(0:1),5)
    X2<-c(2:11)
    dat <- data.frame(X1,X2)
    ANN<-neuralnet(DV ~y,hidden=10,algorithm='rprop+',data=dat)
    return(ANN)
    }

formula<-X1+X2
ANN(formula)
```

Comment: did my response help? i modified your code by combining X1 and X2 in a data frame and using that as the data for neural net. i also changed the function and input.

Comment: Helped but I asked bad question for my case. I edited it. Thanks

Comment: Does it really works? I have this error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'DV' not found. It doesn't see DV, because it is made in the function.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to define DV inside of the function (it will be the same every-time you use the function) you can just use my newly edited function. You just have to change the arguments you give the function to reflect this.

Comment: But that is not the point. For later usage I need to specifiy ,,formula" also as the input to the function so all the objects which I need to use is in the function. I will use expand.grid to create combinations of factor, lets say x and y (as it is in my question) and then run it trough lapply(expand.grid,ANN) so this won't unfortunately work for me ... but thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want so specify the two parts of the formula separately, you should still pass them as formulas.

```
library(neuralnet)
ANN<-function (x,y){
    DV<-rep(c(0:1),5)
    X1<-c(1:10)
    X2<-c(2:11)
    formula<-update(x,y)
    ANN<-neuralnet(formula,data=data.frame(DV,X1,X2),
         hidden=10,algorithm='rprop+')
    return(ANN)
}

ANN(DV~., ~X1+X2)
```

And assuming you're using `neuralnet()` from the `neuralnet` library, it seems the `data=` is required so you'll need to pass in a data.frame with those columns.

Formulas as special because they are not evaluated unless explicitly requested to do so. This is different than just using a symbol, where as soon as you use it is evaluated to something in the proper frame. This means there's a big difference between `DV` (a "name") and `DV~.` (a formula). The latter is safer for passing around to functions and evaluating in a different context. Things get much trickier with symbols/names.